# How do you materialize associations in Ember Data?

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, tastypie

I am trying to wrap my heads around Ember Data ( version 11 ) but am confused about how to materialize association between records. The essence of the problem is that when I call `find` I am getting the an array of DS.Model instances for association fields, but they are not populated with any data except for the 'id' attribute. Resulting in the problem where if I check `Page.get('pictures').toArray()[0].get('text')`,  for example, I get null.

Setting:

Backend, Django + Django REST

Model:

```
class Page( models.Model ):
    text = models.CharField( max_length=30, null=True, blank=True ) 
    picture = models.ManyToManyField( 'Picture', related_name='pictures', null=True, blank=True )

class Picture( models.Model ):
    caption = models.CharField( max_length=30, null=True, blank=True ) 
    page = models.ForeignKey( Page, related_name='page' , null=True, blank=True )
```

The `find` function in the adapter is pretty standard:

```
    find: function(store, type, id) {
        var json = {}
        , root = this.rootForType(type);

        this.ajax(this.buildURL(root, id), "GET", {
            success: function(pre_json) {
                json[root] = pre_json;

                console.log( json )
                Ember.run(this, function(){
                    this.didFindRecord(store, type, json, id);
                });
            }
        });

    },
```

So I'm guessing somewhere in the serializer I should describe how the associations should be materialized? But how would I do this? I tried using the serializer found here:
https://github.com/escalant3/ember-data-tastypie-adapter, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: If you are familiar with django and just need to see what ember's models look like checkout this complex ember example I did just yesterday. It has a set of complex django models with matching ember data models (including the m2m example you show above) https://github.com/toranb/complex-ember-data-example

Comment: Ha, I actually have your example open too! Although I'm not familiar with Django REST framework, may I ask what you had to configure to allow PUT operations, or if there's a resource I should go to to read more about it.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following but PUT was 100% free so long as it's done via the $.ajax side of things (that way the http verb is respected on the server side and the django-rest-framework takes care of the rest)

Comment: Here is a link to my ember-adapter btw https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter

Comment: If I may, when a hasMany array is loaded, are the records inside supposed to be populated with their data? For some reason, when I call 'Session.get('tags').toArray()', I get an array of Tag records, but only their 'id' has been populated, and I get null for all their other fields,

Comment: Correct - my rest backend does not embed the related objects and instead returns a list of int values that represent the pk for each related object. If you want to get the full blown objects don't use toArray - try objectAt(0) instead and use the built in get syntax ember encourages (look for an example in my adapters unit tests if that's not clear enough)